# Removing outliers from 3D plot

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a very long list and if I plot it using:

```
 ListPointPlot3D[ss, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

we can see 3 or 4 outliers. How can I remove them automatically? The list is,

```
ss={{1.59398,0,1.00351},{1.59398,0,1.00351},{0,0.491657,1.00351},{1.59888,0,1.0075},{1.59888,0,1.0075},{0,0.488863,1.0075},{1.60378,0,1.01149},{1.60378,0,1.01149},{0,0.486025,1.01149},{1.60867,0,1.01548},{1.60867,0,1.01548},{0,0.483143,1.01548},{1.61357,0,1.01947},{1.61357,0,1.01947},{0,0.480215,1.01947},{1.61847,0,1.02346},{1.61847,0,1.02346},{0,0.477242,1.02346},{1.62337,0,1.02745},{1.62337,0,1.02745},{0,0.474222,1.02745},{1.62827,0,1.03144},{1.62827,0,1.03144},{0,0.471153,1.03144},{1.63316,0,1.03543},{1.63316,0,1.03543},{0,0.468037,1.03543},{1.63806,0,1.03942},{1.63806,0,1.03942},{0,0.46487,1.03942},{1.64296,0,1.04341},{1.64296,0,1.04341},{0,0.461653,1.04341},{1.64786,0,1.0474},{1.64786,0,1.0474},{0,0.458384,1.0474},{1.65275,0,1.05139},{1.65275,0,1.05139},{0,0.455062,1.05139},{1.65765,0,1.05538},{1.65765,0,1.05538},{0,0.451686,1.05538},{1.66255,0,1.05937},{1.66255,0,1.05937},{0,0.448256,1.05937},{1.66744,0,1.06336},{1.66744,0,1.06336},{0,0.444768,1.06336},{1.67234,0,1.06735},{1.67234,0,1.06735},{0,0.441223,1.06735},{1.67723,0,1.07134},{1.67723,0,1.07134},{0,0.437619,1.07134},{1.68213,0,1.07533},{1.68213,0,1.07533},{0,0.433954,1.07533},{1.68703,0,1.07932},{1.68703,0,1.07932},{0,0.430227,1.07932},{1.69192,0,1.08331},{1.69192,0,1.08331},{0,0.426437,1.08331},{1.69682,0,1.0873},{1.69682,0,1.0873},{0,0.42258,1.0873},{1.70171,0,1.09129},{1.70171,0,1.09129},{0,0.418657,1.09129},{1.70661,0,1.09528},{1.16619,0,1.09528},{0,0.414665,1.09528},{1.71151,0,1.09927},{1.71151,0,1.09927},{0,0.410601,1.09927},{1.7164,0,1.10326},{1.7164,0,1.10326},{0,0.406464,1.10326},{1.7213,0,1.10725},{1.7213,0,1.10725},{0,0.402252,1.10725},{1.72619,0,1.11124},{1.72619,0,1.11124},{0,0.397962,1.11124},{1.73109,0,1.11523},{1.73109,0,1.11523},{0,0.393591,1.11523},{1.73599,0,1.11922},{1.73599,0,1.11922},{0,0.389138,1.11922},{1.74088,0,1.12321},{1.74088,0,1.12321},{0,0.384598,1.12321},{1.74578,0,1.1272},{1.74578,0,1.1272},{0,0.37997,1.1272},{1.75067,0,1.13119},{0,0.375249,1.13119},{1.75557,0,1.13518},{0,0.370432,1.13518},{1.76047,0,1.13917},{0,0.365516,1.13917},{1.76536,0,1.14316},{0,0.360496,1.14316},{1.77026,0,1.14715},{0,0.355368,1.14715},{1.77515,0,1.15114},{0,0.350128,1.15114},{1.78005,0,1.15513},{0,0.344769,1.15513},{1.78495,0,1.15912},{1.78495,0,1.15912},{0,0.339288,1.15912},{1.78984,0,1.16311},{0,0.333676,1.16311},{1.79474,0,1.1671},{0,0.327929,1.1671},{1.79964,0,1.17109},{1.79964,0,1.17109},{0,0.322038,1.17109},{1.80453,0,1.17508},{1.80453,0,1.17508},{0,0.315995,1.17508},{1.80943,0,1.17907},{1.80943,0,1.17907},{0,0.309793,1.17907},{1.81433,0,1.18306},{0,0.30342,1.18306},{1.81922,0,1.18705},{0,0.296867,1.18705},{1.82412,0,1.19104},{0,0.29012,1.19104},{1.82902,0,1.19503},{0,0.283166,1.19503},{1.83392,0,1.19902},{0,0.275989,1.19902},{1.83881,0,1.20301},{0,0.268572,1.20301},{1.84371,0,1.207},{0,0.260894,1.207},{1.84861,0,1.21099},{0,0.252931,1.21099},{1.85351,0,1.21498},{0,0.244656,1.21498},{1.85841,0,1.21897},{0,0.236035,1.21897},{1.86331,0,1.22296},{0,0.227029,1.22296},{1.86821,0,1.22695},{0,0.217591,1.22695},{1.8731,0,1.23094},{0,0.207662,1.23094},{1.878,0,1.23493},{0,0.197167,1.23493},{1.8829,0,1.23892},{0,0.18601,1.23892},{1.8878,0,1.24291},{0,0.174065,1.24291},{1.8927,0,1.2469},{0,0.161157,1.2469},{1.8976,0,1.25089},{1.8976,0,1.25089},{0,0.147031,1.25089},{1.9025,0,1.25488},{1.9025,0,1.25488},{0,0.131296,1.25488},{1.90741,0,1.25887},{1.90741,0,1.25887},{0,0.113282,1.25887},{1.91231,0,1.26286},{1.91231,0,1.26286},{0,0.0916566,1.26286},{1.91721,0,1.26685},{0,0.0627928,1.26685},{1.92211,0,1.27084},{1.92211,0,1.27084},{0.0232637,0,1.27084},{1.92701,0,1.27483},{1.92701,0,1.27483},{0.0710737,0,1.27483},{1.93191,0,1.27882},{1.93191,0,1.27882},{0.0979177,0,1.27882},{1.93682,0,1.28281},{1.93682,0,1.28281},{0.118955,0,1.28281},{1.94172,0,1.2868},{1.94172,0,1.2868},{0.136891,0,1.2868},{1.94662,0,1.29079},{1.94662,0,1.29079},{0.152819,0,1.29079},{1.95152,0,1.29478},{0.167316,0,1.29478},{1.95643,0,1.29877},{0.180725,0,1.29877},{1.96133,0,1.30276},{1.96133,0,1.30276},{0.193274,0,1.30276},{1.96624,0,1.30675},{1.96624,0,1.30675},{0.205119,0,1.30675},{1.97114,0,1.31074},{0.216378,0,1.31074},{1.97605,0,1.31473},{0.227136,0,1.31473},{1.98095,0,1.31872},{1.98095,0,1.31872},{0.237462,0,1.31872},{1.98586,0,1.32271},{1.98586,0,1.32271},{0.24741,0,1.32271},{1.99076,0,1.3267},{1.99076,0,1.3267},{0.257024,0,1.3267},{1.99567,0,1.33069},{0.266341,0,1.33069},{2.00057,0,1.33468},{2.00057,0,1.33468},{0.275389,0,1.33468},{2.00548,0,1.33867},{2.00548,0,1.33867},{0.284196,0,1.33867},{2.01039,0,1.34266},{2.01039,0,1.34266},{0.292782,0,1.34266},{2.0153,0,1.34665},{0.301167,0,1.34665},{2.0202,0,1.35064},{2.0202,0,1.35064},{0.309367,0,1.35064},{2.02511,0,1.35463},{2.02511,0,1.35463},{0.317396,0,1.35463},{2.03002,0,1.35862},{2.03002,0,1.35862},{0.325267,0,1.35862},{2.03493,0,1.36261},{2.03493,0,1.36261},{0.332991,0,1.36261},{2.03984,0,1.3666},{2.03984,0,1.3666},{0.340579,0,1.3666},{2.04475,0,1.37059},{2.04475,0,1.37059},{0.348038,0,1.37059},{2.04966,0,1.37458},{2.04966,0,1.37458},{0.355378,0,1.37458},{2.05457,0,1.37857},{0.362605,0,1.37857},{2.05948,0,1.38256},{0.369727,0,1.38256},{2.06439,0,1.38655},{0.376748,0,1.38655},{2.0693,0,1.39054},{0.383675,0,1.39054},{2.07421,0,1.39453},{0.390512,0,1.39453},{2.07912,0,1.39852},{0.397265,0,1.39852},{2.08404,0,1.40251},{0.403937,0,1.40251},{0.403937,0,1.40251},{2.08895,0,1.4065},{0.410532,0,1.4065},{0.410532,0,1.4065},{2.09386,0,1.41049},{0.417055,0,1.41049},{0.417055,0,1.41049},{2.09878,0,1.41448},{0.423508,0,1.41448},{0.423508,0,1.41448},{2.10369,0,1.41847},{0.429894,0,1.41847},{0.429894,0,1.41847},{2.1086,0,1.42246},{0.436217,0,1.42246},{0.436217,0,1.42246},{2.11352,0,1.42645},{0.44248,0,1.42645},{0.44248,0,1.42645},{2.11843,0,1.43044},{0.448683,0,1.43044},{0.448683,0,1.43044},{2.12335,0,1.43443},{0.454832,0,1.43443},{0.454832,0,1.43443},{2.12827,0,1.43842},{0.460926,0,1.43842},{0.460926,0,1.43842},{2.13318,0,1.44241},{0.466969,0,1.44241},{0.466969,0,1.44241},{2.1381,0,1.4464},{0.472962,0,1.4464},{0.472962,0,1.4464},{2.14302,0,1.45039},{0.478908,0,1.45039},{0.478908,0,1.45039},{2.14794,0,1.45438},{0.484808,0,1.45438},{0.484808,0,1.45438},{2.15285,0,1.45837},{0.490664,0,1.45837},{0.490664,0,1.45837},{2.15777,0,1.46236},{0.496476,0,1.46236},{0.496476,0,1.46236},{2.16269,0,1.46635},{0.502248,0,1.46635},{0.502248,0,1.46635},{2.16761,0,1.47034},{0.50798,0,1.47034},{0.50798,0,1.47034},{2.17253,0,1.47433},{0.513674,0,1.47433},{0.513674,0,1.47433},{2.17745,0,1.47832},{0.51933,0,1.47832},{0.51933,0,1.47832},{2.18237,0,1.48231},{0.524951,0,1.48231},{0.524951,0,1.48231},{2.18729,0,1.4863},{0.530537,0,1.4863},{0.530537,0,1.4863},{2.19221,0,1.49029},{0.536089,0,1.49029},{0.536089,0,1.49029},{2.19714,0,1.49428},{0.541608,0,1.49428},{0.541608,0,1.49428},{2.20206,0,1.49827},{0.547096,0,1.49827},{0.547096,0,1.49827},{2.20698,0,1.50226},{0.552553,0,1.50226},{0.552553,0,1.50226},{2.21191,0,1.50625},{0.55798,0,1.50625},{0.55798,0,1.50625},{2.21683,0,1.51024},{0.563378,0,1.51024},{0.563378,0,1.51024},{2.22175,0,1.51423},{0.568748,0,1.51423},{0.568748,0,1.51423},{2.22668,0,1.51822},{0.574091,0,1.51822},{0.574091,0,1.51822},{2.2316,0,1.52221},{0.579408,0,1.52221},{0.579408,0,1.52221},{2.23653,0,1.5262},{0.584698,0,1.5262},{0.584698,0,1.5262},{2.24146,0,1.53019},{0.589964,0,1.53019},{0.589964,0,1.53019},{2.24638,0,1.53418},{0.595205,0,1.53418},{0.595205,0,1.53418},{2.25131,0,1.53817},{0.600422,0,1.53817},{0.600422,0,1.53817},{2.25624,0,1.54216},{0.605617,0,1.54216},{0.605617,0,1.54216},{2.26117,0,1.54615},{0.610788,0,1.54615},{0.610788,0,1.54615},{2.26609,0,1.55014},{0.615938,0,1.55014},{0.615938,0,1.55014},{2.27102,0,1.55413},{0.621067,0,1.55413},{0.621067,0,1.55413},{2.27595,0,1.55812},{0.626174,0,1.55812},{0.626174,0,1.55812},{2.28088,0,1.56211},{0.631261,0,1.56211},{0.631261,0,1.56211},{2.28581,0,1.5661},{0.636329,0,1.5661},{0.636329,0,1.5661},{2.29074,0,1.57009},{0.641377,0,1.57009},{0.641377,0,1.57009},{2.29568,0,1.57408},{0.646406,0,1.57408},{0.646406,0,1.57408},{2.30061,0,1.57807},{0.651417,0,1.57807},{0.651417,0,1.57807},{2.30554,0,1.58206},{0.656409,0,1.58206},{0.656409,0,1.58206},{2.31047,0,1.58605},{0.661384,0,1.58605},{0.661384,0,1.58605},{2.31541,0,1.59004},{0.666342,0,1.59004},{0.666342,0,1.59004},{2.32034,0,1.59403},{0.671283,0,1.59403},{0.671283,0,1.59403},{2.32527,0,1.59802},{0.676208,0,1.59802},{0.676208,0,1.59802},{2.33021,0,1.60201},{0.681117,0,1.60201},{0.681117,0,1.60201},{2.33514,0,1.606},{0.68601,0,1.606},{0.68601,0,1.606},{2.34008,0,1.60999},{0.690888,0,1.60999},{0.690888,0,1.60999},{2.34502,0,1.61398},{0.69575,0,1.61398},{0.69575,0,1.61398},{2.34995,0,1.61797},{0.700598,0,1.61797},{0.700598,0,1.61797},{2.35489,0,1.62196},{0.705432,0,1.62196},{0.705432,0,1.62196},{2.35983,0,1.62595},{0.710252,0,1.62595},{0.710252,0,1.62595},{2.36477,0,1.62994},{0.715058,0,1.62994},{0.715058,0,1.62994},{2.3697,0,1.63393},{0.71985,0,1.63393},{0.71985,0,1.63393},{2.37464,0,1.63792},{0.724629,0,1.63792},{0.724629,0,1.63792},{2.37958,0,1.64191},{0.729396,0,1.64191},{0.729396,0,1.64191},{2.38452,0,1.6459},{0.734149,0,1.6459},{0.734149,0,1.6459},{2.38946,0,1.64989},{0.738891,0,1.64989},{0.738891,0,1.64989},{2.3944,0,1.65388},{0.74362,0,1.65388},{0.74362,0,1.65388},{2.39935,0,1.65787},{0.748338,0,1.65787},{0.748338,0,1.65787},{2.40429,0,1.66186},{0.753043,0,1.66186},{0.753043,0,1.66186},{2.40923,0,1.66585},{0.757738,0,1.66585},{0.757738,0,1.66585},{2.41417,0,1.66984},{0.762421,0,1.66984},{0.762421,0,1.66984},{2.41912,0,1.67383},{0.767093,0,1.67383},{0.767093,0,1.67383},{2.42406,0,1.67782},{0.771755,0,1.67782},{0.771755,0,1.67782},{2.42901,0,1.68181},{0.776405,0,1.68181},{0.776405,0,1.68181},{2.43395,0,1.6858},{0.781046,0,1.6858},{0.781046,0,1.6858},{2.4389,0,1.68979},{0.785677,0,1.68979},{0.785677,0,1.68979},{2.44384,0,1.69378},{0.790297,0,1.69378},{0.790297,0,1.69378},{2.44879,0,1.69777},{0.794908,0,1.69777},{0.794908,0,1.69777},{2.45374,0,1.70176},{0.799509,0,1.70176},{0.799509,0,1.70176},{2.45869,0,1.70575},{0.804101,0,1.70575},{0.804101,0,1.70575},{2.46363,0,1.70974},{0.808684,0,1.70974},{0.808684,0,1.70974},{2.46858,0,1.71373},{0.813257,0,1.71373},{0.813257,0,1.71373},{2.47353,0,1.71772},{0.817822,0,1.71772},{0.817822,0,1.71772},{2.47848,0,1.72171},{0.822378,0,1.72171},{0.822378,0,1.72171},{2.48343,0,1.7257},{0.826926,0,1.7257},{0.826926,0,1.7257},{2.48838,0,1.72969},{0.831465,0,1.72969},{0.831465,0,1.72969},{2.49333,0,1.73368},{0.835996,0,1.73368},{0.835996,0,1.73368},{2.49829,0,1.73767},{0.840519,0,1.73767},{0.840519,0,1.73767},{2.50324,0,1.74166},{0.845034,0,1.74166},{0.845034,0,1.74166},{2.50819,0,1.74565},{0.849541,0,1.74565},{0.849541,0,1.74565},{2.51314,0,1.74964},{0.854041,0,1.74964},{0.854041,0,1.74964},{2.5181,0,1.75363},{0.858533,0,1.75363},{0.858533,0,1.75363},{2.52305,0,1.75762},{0.863018,0,1.75762},{0.863018,0,1.75762},{2.52801,0,1.76161},{0.867495,0,1.76161},{0.867495,0,1.76161},{2.53296,0,1.7656},{0.871966,0,1.7656},{0.871966,0,1.7656},{2.53792,0,1.76959},{0.876429,0,1.76959},{0.876429,0,1.76959},{2.54287,0,1.77358},{0.880886,0,1.77358},{0.880886,0,1.77358},{2.54783,0,1.77757},{0.885336,0,1.77757},{0.885336,0,1.77757},{2.55279,0,1.78156},{0.889779,0,1.78156},{0.889779,0,1.78156},{2.55775,0,1.78555},{0.894216,0,1.78555},{0.894216,0,1.78555},{2.56271,0,1.78954},{0.898647,0,1.78954},{0.898647,0,1.78954},{2.56766,0,1.79353},{0.903071,0,1.79353},{0.903071,0,1.79353},{2.57262,0,1.79752},{0.907489,0,1.79752},{0.907489,0,1.79752},{2.57758,0,1.80151},{0.911901,0,1.80151},{0.911901,0,1.80151},{2.58254,0,1.8055},{0.916307,0,1.8055},{0.916307,0,1.8055},{2.58751,0,1.80949},{0.920708,0,1.80949},{0.920708,0,1.80949},{2.59247,0,1.81348},{0.925103,0,1.81348},{0.925103,0,1.81348},{2.59743,0,1.81747},{0.929492,0,1.81747},{0.929492,0,1.81747},{2.60239,0,1.82146},{0.933875,0,1.82146},{0.933875,0,1.82146},{2.60736,0,1.82545},{0.938253,0,1.82545},{0.938253,0,1.82545},{2.61232,0,1.82944},{0.942626,0,1.82944},{0.942626,0,1.82944},{2.61728,0,1.83343},{0.946994,0,1.83343},{0.946994,0,1.83343},{2.62225,0,1.83742},{0.951356,0,1.83742},{0.951356,0,1.83742},{2.62721,0,1.84141},{0.955714,0,1.84141},{0.955714,0,1.84141},{2.63218,0,1.8454},{0.960066,0,1.8454},{0.960066,0,1.8454},{2.63715,0,1.84939},{0.964414,0,1.84939},{0.964414,0,1.84939},{2.64211,0,1.85338},{0.968757,0,1.85338},{0.968757,0,1.85338},{2.64708,0,1.85737},{0.973095,0,1.85737},{0.973095,0,1.85737},{2.65205,0,1.86136},{0.977429,0,1.86136},{0.977429,0,1.86136},{2.65702,0,1.86535},{0.981758,0,1.86535},{0.981758,0,1.86535},{2.66198,0,1.86934},{0.986083,0,1.86934},{0.986083,0,1.86934},{2.66695,0,1.87333},{0.990404,0,1.87333},{0.990404,0,1.87333},{2.67192,0,1.87732},{0.99472,0,1.87732},{0.99472,0,1.87732},{2.67689,0,1.88131},{0.999032,0,1.88131},{0.999032,0,1.88131},{2.68187,0,1.8853},{2.68187,0,1.8853},{1.00334,0,1.8853},{2.68684,0,1.88929},{2.68684,0,1.88929},{1.00764,0,1.88929},{2.69181,0,1.89328},{2.69181,0,1.89328},{1.01194,0,1.89328},{2.69678,0,1.89727},{2.69678,0,1.89727},{1.01624,0,1.89727},{2.70176,0,1.90126},{2.70176,0,1.90126},{1.02053,0,1.90126},{2.70673,0,1.90525},{2.70673,0,1.90525},{1.02482,0,1.90525},{2.7117,0,1.90924},{2.7117,0,1.90924},{1.02911,0,1.90924},{2.71668,0,1.91323},{2.71668,0,1.91323},{1.03339,0,1.91323},{2.72165,0,1.91722},{2.72165,0,1.91722},{1.03766,0,1.91722},{2.72663,0,1.92121},{2.72663,0,1.92121},{1.04194,0,1.92121},{2.7316,0,1.9252},{2.7316,0,1.9252},{1.04621,0,1.9252},{2.73658,0,1.92919},{2.73658,0,1.92919},{1.05048,0,1.92919},{2.74156,0,1.93318},{2.74156,0,1.93318},{1.05474,0,1.93318},{2.74654,0,1.93717},{2.74654,0,1.93717},{1.059,0,1.93717},{2.75151,0,1.94116},{2.75151,0,1.94116},{1.06326,0,1.94116},{2.75649,0,1.94515},{2.75649,0,1.94515},{1.06752,0,1.94515},{2.76147,0,1.94914},{2.76147,0,1.94914},{1.07177,0,1.94914},{2.76645,0,1.95313},{2.76645,0,1.95313},{1.07602,0,1.95313},{2.77143,0,1.95712},{2.77143,0,1.95712},{1.08026,0,1.95712},{2.77641,0,1.96111},{2.77641,0,1.96111},{1.08451,0,1.96111},{2.7814,0,1.9651},{2.7814,0,1.9651},{1.08875,0,1.9651},{2.78638,0,1.96909},{2.78638,0,1.96909},{1.09299,0,1.96909},{2.79136,0,1.97308},{2.79136,0,1.97308},{1.09722,0,1.97308},{2.79634,0,1.97707},{2.79634,0,1.97707},{1.10145,0,1.97707},{2.80133,0,1.98106},{2.80133,0,1.98106},{1.10569,0,1.98106},{2.80631,0,1.98505},{2.80631,0,1.98505},{1.10991,0,1.98505},{2.8113,0,1.98904},{2.8113,0,1.98904},{1.11414,0,1.98904},{2.81628,0,1.99303},{2.81628,0,1.99303},{1.11836,0,1.99303},{2.82127,0,1.99702},{2.82127,0,1.99702},{1.12258,0,1.99702},{2.82625,0,2.00101},{2.82625,0,2.00101},{1.1268,0,2.00101},{2.83124,0,2.005},{2.83124,0,2.005},{1.13102,0,2.005},{2.83623,0,2.00899},{2.83623,0,2.00899},{1.13523,0,2.00899},{2.84121,0,2.01298},{2.84121,0,2.01298},{1.13945,0,2.01298},{2.8462,0,2.01697},{2.8462,0,2.01697},{1.14366,0,2.01697},{2.85119,0,2.02096},{1.14786,0,2.02096},{2.85618,0,2.02495},{1.15207,0,2.02495},{2.86117,0,2.02894},{1.15627,0,2.02894},{2.86616,0,2.03293},{2.86616,0,2.03293},{1.16048,0,2.03293},{2.87115,0,2.03692},{2.87115,0,2.03692},{1.16468,0,2.03692},{2.87614,0,2.04091},{1.16888,0,2.04091},{2.88113,0,2.0449},{1.17308,0,2.0449},{1.17308,0,2.0449},{2.88613,0,2.04889},{1.17727,0,2.04889},{1.17727,0,2.04889},{2.89112,0,2.05288},{1.18147,0,2.05288},{1.18147,0,2.05288},{2.89611,0,2.05687},{1.18566,0,2.05687},{1.18566,0,2.05687},{2.90111,0,2.06086},{1.18985,0,2.06086},{1.18985,0,2.06086},{2.9061,0,2.06485},{1.19404,0,2.06485},{1.19404,0,2.06485},{2.9111,0,2.06884},{1.19823,0,2.06884},{1.19823,0,2.06884},{2.91609,0,2.07283},{1.20242,0,2.07283},{1.20242,0,2.07283},{2.92109,0,2.07682},{1.2066,0,2.07682},{1.2066,0,2.07682},{2.92608,0,2.08081},{1.21079,0,2.08081},{1.21079,0,2.08081},{2.93108,0,2.0848},{1.21497,0,2.0848},{1.21497,0,2.0848},{2.93608,0,2.08879},{1.21916,0,2.08879},{1.21916,0,2.08879},{2.94108,0,2.09278},{1.22334,0,2.09278},{2.94607,0,2.09677},{1.22752,0,2.09677},{2.95107,0,2.10076},{1.2317,0,2.10076},{2.95607,0,2.10475},{1.23588,0,2.10475},{2.96107,0,2.10874},{1.24005,0,2.10874},{2.96607,0,2.11273},{1.24423,0,2.11273},{2.97107,0,2.11672},{1.24841,0,2.11672},{2.97608,0,2.12071},{1.25258,0,2.12071},{2.98108,0,2.1247},{1.25676,0,2.1247},{2.98608,0,2.12869},{1.26093,0,2.12869},{2.99108,0,2.13268},{1.2651,0,2.13268},{2.99609,0,2.13667},{1.26928,0,2.13667},{1.27345,0,2.14066},{1.27762,0,2.14465},{1.28179,0,2.14864},{1.28596,0,2.15263},{1.29013,0,2.15662},{1.2943,0,2.16061},{1.29847,0,2.1646},{1.30264,0,2.16859},{1.30681,0,2.17258},{1.31098,0,2.17657},{1.31515,0,2.18056},{1.31932,0,2.18455},{1.31932,0,2.18455},{1.32349,0,2.18854},{1.32349,0,2.18854},{1.32765,0,2.19253},{1.32765,0,2.19253},{1.33182,0,2.19652},{1.33182,0,2.19652},{1.33599,0,2.20051},{1.33599,0,2.20051},{1.34016,0,2.2045},{1.34016,0,2.2045},{1.34433,0,2.20849},{1.34433,0,2.20849},{1.3485,0,2.21248},{1.3485,0,2.21248},{1.3485,0,2.21248},{1.3485,0,2.21248},{1.35267,0,2.21647},{1.35267,0,2.21647},{1.35267,0,2.21647},{1.35684,0,2.22046},{1.35684,0,2.22046},{1.35684,0,2.22046},{1.36101,0,2.22445},{1.36101,0,2.22445},{1.36101,0,2.22445},{1.36518,0,2.22844},{1.36518,0,2.22844},{1.36518,0,2.22844},{1.36935,0,2.23243},{1.36935,0,2.23243},{1.36935,0,2.23243},{1.37352,0,2.23642},{1.37352,0,2.23642},{1.37352,0,2.23642},{1.37769,0,2.24041},{1.37769,0,2.24041},{1.37769,0,2.24041},{1.38187,0,2.2444},{1.38187,0,2.2444},{1.38187,0,2.2444},{1.38604,0,2.24839},{1.38604,0,2.24839},{1.38604,0,2.24839},{1.39021,0,2.25238},{1.39021,0,2.25238},{1.39021,0,2.25238},{1.39439,0,2.25637},{1.39439,0,2.25637},{1.39439,0,2.25637},{1.39856,0,2.26036},{1.39856,0,2.26036},{1.39856,0,2.26036},{1.40274,0,2.26435},{1.40274,0,2.26435},{1.40274,0,2.26435},{1.40691,0,2.26834},{1.40691,0,2.26834},{1.40691,0,2.26834},{1.41109,0,2.27233},{1.41109,0,2.27233},{1.41109,0,2.27233},{1.41527,0,2.27632},{1.41527,0,2.27632},{1.41527,0,2.27632},{1.41945,0,2.28031},{1.41945,0,2.28031},{1.41945,0,2.28031},{1.42363,0,2.2843},{1.42363,0,2.2843},{1.42363,0,2.2843},{1.42781,0,2.28829},{1.42781,0,2.28829},{1.42781,0,2.28829},{1.43199,0,2.29228},{1.43199,0,2.29228},{1.43199,0,2.29228},{1.43617,0,2.29627},{1.43617,0,2.29627},{1.43617,0,2.29627},{1.44035,0,2.30026},{1.44035,0,2.30026},{1.44035,0,2.30026},{1.44454,0,2.30425},{1.44454,0,2.30425},{1.44454,0,2.30425},{1.44872,0,2.30824},{1.44872,0,2.30824},{1.44872,0,2.30824},{1.45291,0,2.31223},{1.45291,0,2.31223},{1.45291,0,2.31223},{1.4571,0,2.31622},{1.4571,0,2.31622},{1.4571,0,2.31622},{1.46129,0,2.32021},{1.46129,0,2.32021},{1.46129,0,2.32021},{1.46548,0,2.3242},{1.46548,0,2.3242},{1.46548,0,2.3242},{1.46967,0,2.32819},{1.46967,0,2.32819},{1.47387,0,2.33218},{1.47387,0,2.33218},{1.47806,0,2.33617},{1.47806,0,2.33617},{1.48226,0,2.34016},{1.48226,0,2.34016},{1.48646,0,2.34415},{1.48646,0,2.34415},{1.49066,0,2.34814},{1.49066,0,2.34814},{1.49486,0,2.35213},{1.49486,0,2.35213},{1.49906,0,2.35612},{1.49906,0,2.35612},{1.50326,0,2.36011},{1.50326,0,2.36011},{1.50747,0,2.3641},{1.50747,0,2.3641},{1.51168,0,2.36809},{1.51168,0,2.36809},{1.51589,0,2.37208},{1.51589,0,2.37208},{1.5201,0,2.37607},{1.5201,0,2.37607},{1.52431,0,2.38006},{1.52431,0,2.38006},{1.52853,0,2.38405},{1.52853,0,2.38405},{1.53275,0,2.38804},{1.53275,0,2.38804},{1.53696,0,2.39203},{1.53696,0,2.39203},{1.54119,0,2.39602},{1.54119,0,2.39602},{1.54541,0,2.40001},{1.54541,0,2.40001},{1.54964,0,2.404},{1.54964,0,2.404},{1.55386,0,2.40799},{1.55386,0,2.40799},{1.55809,0,2.41198},{1.55809,0,2.41198},{1.56233,0,2.41597},{1.56233,0,2.41597},{1.56233,0,2.41597},{1.56656,0,2.41996},{1.56656,0,2.41996},{1.56656,0,2.41996},{1.5708,0,2.42395},{1.5708,0,2.42395},{1.5708,0,2.42395},{1.57504,0,2.42794},{1.57504,0,2.42794},{1.57504,0,2.42794},{1.57928,0,2.43193},{1.57928,0,2.43193},{1.58352,0,2.43592},{1.58352,0,2.43592},{1.58777,0,2.43991},{1.58777,0,2.43991},{1.59202,0,2.4439},{1.59202,0,2.4439},{1.59627,0,2.44789},{1.59627,0,2.44789},{1.60052,0,2.45188},{1.60052,0,2.45188},{1.60478,0,2.45587},{1.60478,0,2.45587},{1.60904,0,2.45986},{1.60904,0,2.45986},{1.6133,0,2.46385},{1.6133,0,2.46385},{1.61757,0,2.46784},{1.61757,0,2.46784},{1.62184,0,2.47183},{1.62184,0,2.47183},{1.62611,0,2.47582},{1.62611,0,2.47582},{1.63038,0,2.47981},{1.63038,0,2.47981},{1.63466,0,2.4838},{1.63466,0,2.4838},{1.63894,0,2.48779},{1.63894,0,2.48779},{1.64322,0,2.49178},{1.64322,0,2.49178},{1.64751,0,2.49577},{1.73789,0,2.49577},{1.6518,0,2.49976},{1.6518,0,2.49976},{1.65609,0,2.50375},{1.65609,0,2.50375},{1.66039,0,2.50774},{1.66039,0,2.50774},{1.66469,0,2.51173},{1.76381,0,2.51173},{1.66899,0,2.51572},{1.66899,0,2.51572},{1.6733,0,2.51971},{1.6733,0,2.51971},{1.6776,0,2.5237},{1.6776,0,2.5237},{1.68192,0,2.52769},{1.68192,0,2.52769},{1.68623,0,2.53168},{1.68623,0,2.53168},{1.69055,0,2.53567},{1.69055,0,2.53567},{1.69488,0,2.53966},{1.69488,0,2.53966},{1.69921,0,2.54365},{1.69921,0,2.54365},{1.70354,0,2.54764},{1.70354,0,2.54764},{1.70787,0,2.55163},{1.70787,0,2.55163},{1.71221,0,2.55562},{1.71221,0,2.55562},{1.71655,0,2.55961},{1.71655,0,2.55961},{1.7209,0,2.5636},{1.7209,0,2.5636},{1.72525,0,2.56759},{1.72525,0,2.56759},{1.72961,0,2.57158},{1.72961,0,2.57158},{1.73396,0,2.57557},{1.73396,0,2.57557},{1.73833,0,2.57956},{1.73833,0,2.57956},{1.74269,0,2.58355},{1.74269,0,2.58355},{1.74707,0,2.58754},{1.74707,0,2.58754},{1.75144,0,2.59153},{1.75144,0,2.59153},{1.75582,0,2.59552},{1.75582,0,2.59552},{1.76021,0,2.59951},{1.76021,0,2.59951},{1.76459,0,2.6035},{1.76459,0,2.6035},{1.76899,0,2.60749},{1.76899,0,2.60749},{1.77339,0,2.61148},{1.77339,0,2.61148},{1.77779,0,2.61547},{1.77779,0,2.61547},{1.7822,0,2.61946},{1.7822,0,2.61946},{1.78661,0,2.62345},{1.78661,0,2.62345},{1.79102,0,2.62744},{1.79102,0,2.62744},{1.79544,0,2.63143},{1.79544,0,2.63143},{1.79987,0,2.63542},{1.79987,0,2.63542},{1.8043,0,2.63941},{1.8043,0,2.63941},{1.80874,0,2.6434},{1.80874,0,2.6434},{1.81318,0,2.64739},{1.81305,0,2.64739},{1.81763,0,2.65138},{1.81763,0,2.65138},{1.82208,0,2.65537},{1.82208,0,2.65537},{1.82653,0,2.65936},{1.82653,0,2.65936},{1.831,0,2.66335},{1.831,0,2.66335},{1.83546,0,2.66734},{1.83546,0,2.66734},{1.83994,0,2.67133},{1.83994,0,2.67133},{1.84441,0,2.67532},{1.84441,0,2.67532},{1.8489,0,2.67931},{1.8489,0,2.67931},{1.85339,0,2.6833},{1.85339,0,2.6833},{1.85788,0,2.68729},{1.85788,0,2.68729},{1.86238,0,2.69128},{1.86238,0,2.69128},{1.86689,0,2.69527},{1.86689,0,2.69527},{1.8714,0,2.69926},{1.8714,0,2.69926},{1.87592,0,2.70325},{1.87592,0,2.70325},{1.87592,0,2.70325},{1.88044,0,2.70724},{1.88044,0,2.70724},{1.88044,0,2.70724},{1.88497,0,2.71123},{1.88497,0,2.71123},{1.88497,0,2.71123},{1.8895,0,2.71522},{1.8895,0,2.71522},{1.89405,0,2.71921},{1.89405,0,2.71921},{1.89859,0,2.7232},{1.89859,0,2.7232},{1.89859,0,2.7232},{1.90315,0,2.72719},{1.90315,0,2.72719},{1.90315,0,2.72719},{1.90771,0,2.73118},{1.90771,0,2.73118},{1.90771,0,2.73118},{1.91227,0,2.73517},{1.91227,0,2.73517},{1.91227,0,2.73517},{1.91685,0,2.73916},{1.91685,0,2.73916},{1.92143,0,2.74315},{1.92143,0,2.74315},{1.92601,0,2.74714},{1.92601,0,2.74714},{1.93061,0,2.75113},{1.93061,0,2.75113},{1.9352,0,2.75512},{1.9352,0,2.75512},{1.93981,0,2.75911},{1.93981,0,2.75911},{1.94442,0,2.7631},{1.94442,0,2.7631},{1.94904,0,2.76709},{1.94904,0,2.76709},{1.95367,0,2.77108},{1.95367,0,2.77108},{1.9583,0,2.77507},{1.9583,0,2.77507},{1.96294,0,2.77906},{1.96294,0,2.77906},{1.96759,0,2.78305},{1.96759,0,2.78305},{1.97225,0,2.78704},{1.97225,0,2.78704},{1.97691,0,2.79103},{1.97691,0,2.79103},{1.98158,0,2.79502},{1.98158,0,2.79502},{1.98625,0,2.79901},{1.98625,0,2.79901},{1.99094,0,2.803},{1.99094,0,2.803},{1.99563,0,2.80699},{1.99563,0,2.80699},{2.00033,0,2.81098},{2.00033,0,2.81098},{2.00503,0,2.81497},{2.00503,0,2.81497},{2.00975,0,2.81896},{2.00975,0,2.81896},{2.01447,0,2.82295},{2.01447,0,2.82295},{2.0192,0,2.82694},{2.0192,0,2.82694},{2.02394,0,2.83093},{2.02394,0,2.83093},{2.02869,0,2.83492},{2.02869,0,2.83492},{2.03344,0,2.83891},{2.03344,0,2.83891},{2.0382,0,2.8429},{2.0382,0,2.8429},{2.04297,0,2.84689},{2.04297,0,2.84689},{2.04775,0,2.85088},{2.04775,0,2.85088},{2.05254,0,2.85487},{2.05254,0,2.85487},{2.05733,0,2.85886},{2.05733,0,2.85886},{2.06214,0,2.86285},{2.06214,0,2.86285},{2.06695,0,2.86684},{2.06695,0,2.86684},{2.07177,0,2.87083},{2.07177,0,2.87083},{2.0766,0,2.87482},{2.0766,0,2.87482},{2.08144,0,2.87881},{2.08144,0,2.87881},{2.08629,0,2.8828},{2.08629,0,2.8828},{2.09115,0,2.88679},{2.09115,0,2.88679},{2.09601,0,2.89078},{2.09601,0,2.89078},{2.10089,0,2.89477},{2.10089,0,2.89477},{2.10577,0,2.89876},{2.10577,0,2.89876},{2.11066,0,2.90275},{2.11066,0,2.90275},{2.11557,0,2.90674},{2.11557,0,2.90674},{2.12048,0,2.91073},{2.12048,0,2.91073},{2.1254,0,2.91472},{2.1254,0,2.91472},{2.13033,0,2.91871},{2.13033,0,2.91871},{2.13527,0,2.9227},{2.13527,0,2.9227},{2.14022,0,2.92669},{2.14022,0,2.92669},{2.14518,0,2.93068},{2.14518,0,2.93068},{2.15015,0,2.93467},{2.15015,0,2.93467},{2.15513,0,2.93866},{2.15513,0,2.93866},{2.16012,0,2.94265},{2.16012,0,2.94265},{2.16512,0,2.94664},{2.16512,0,2.94664},{2.17013,0,2.95063},{2.17013,0,2.95063},{2.17515,0,2.95462},{2.17515,0,2.95462},{2.18018,0,2.95861},{2.18018,0,2.95861},{2.18522,0,2.9626},{2.18522,0,2.9626},{2.19027,0,2.96659},{2.19027,0,2.96659},{2.19534,0,2.97058},{2.19534,0,2.97058},{2.20041,0,2.97457},{2.20041,0,2.97457},{2.20549,0,2.97856},{2.20549,0,2.97856},{2.21058,0,2.98255},{2.21058,0,2.98255},{2.21569,0,2.98654},{2.21569,0,2.98654},{2.2208,0,2.99053},{2.2208,0,2.99053},{2.22593,0,2.99452},{2.22593,0,2.99452},{2.23107,0,2.99851},{2.23107,0,2.99851}}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this answer by @Anton Antonov : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114012/finding-outliers-in-2d-and-3d-numerical-data?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Ali, that would help if data are lumped somewhere. However, my data builds branches in 3d.