# Edited: Cannot reproduce the same plots with the same code

Tags: plotting, wolfram-cloud

I am trying to import a file from the cloud (wolfram cloud), but i got the error

```
Part :Part specification Sign In with Your Wolfram ID
```

mycode:

```
data = Import["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/name/Online%20Retail.csv", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True, "HeaderLines" -> 0];

columnNames = data[[1]];

data = Rest[data];

Dimensions[data]
```

edited:
So I have successfully? loaded the data. And here is my output...
[image]

However, I still cannot produce the same outcome (the grid and plot) as in the first comment of [Finding outliers in 2D and 3D numerical data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114012/finding-outliers-in-2d-and-3d-numerical-data/114032#114032), Help!

Comment: The obvious question: Are you signed in when attempting to do this?

Comment: You need to either CloudConnect first on your desktop Mathematica and then Use CloudImport[CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/name/Online%20Retail.csv"]...] to import the file.

Comment: Hint: did the data actually load? The file is not accessible publicly. If you can see it while logged into the Wolfram Cloud site, then you need to ensure that Mathematica is also able to access that content. What is the output if you only run the first line (the Import command) without the semicolon?

Comment: I edited the question