# Failure in reproducing plots in a post

Tags: plotting

I am trying to reproduce the plots in this post [Finding outliers in 2D and 3D numerical data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114012/finding-outliers-in-2d-and-3d-numerical-data/114032#114032) with my own data.

However, I am new to the wolfram language (I used to use R). I don't quit understanding what's going on in the codes. Here're some rows of my data:
[image]

I want to create a 3D Quantile Regression envelopes to find the outliers as in the post, with the varible Age, Ratio.bp, and Ratio.heart. However, I can't get any the plots. Here's an example:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
testData = N@data[[All, {2, 5, 8}]];
sTestData = Transpose[Standardize /@ Transpose[N@testData]];
Block[{offset = -2 (Min /@ Transpose[sTestData])}, 
  sTestData = Map[# + offset &, sTestData]];
opts = {PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed"};
Grid[{{ListPointPlot3D[sTestData, opts], 
   ListPointPlot3D[sTestData, opts]}}]
```

What did i did wrong?

- I don't know how to upload the file, but i `dput` my file in R and here's the code: https://codeshare.io/alRLNY
- I uploaded the csv file: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/3676944d24cb54ae4adcd8d34e0f2435/new_heart_data.csv

Comment: @Anton Antonov Do you mind to help with this question?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1898354).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems

The data contains non-numeric values e.g. "NA". You will have to remove those rows or impute the missing values using e.g. [`SynthesizeMissingValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SynthesizeMissingValues.html).

The header row needs to be excluded as well, so do this and the rest of the code will work

```
data = Import["~/Downloads/new_heart_data.csv"];
testData = data[[2 ;;, {2, 5, 8}]] // Select[FreeQ[#, "NA"] &];
```